# MVC 5 Jquery Load - Catching Inner Exception

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, exception

I have a partial view which loads a ObjectResult from a SQL procedure. This is using the built in EF method.

```
public virtual ObjectResult<Something_Result> getSomething()
{
    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Something_Result>("getSomething");
}
```

So a usual problem is timeouts from the database and I would like to show this. But I cant seem to find this in the exception object from the Ajax.Load() functon .
In the responseText I only get `"{"message":"An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details."}"` and with status: 500

So is it an easy way to get the inner exception aswell?
Here is the exception thrown by the Ajax.load() function https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAtNo.jpg
And here is the Inner Exception from EF: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4H5wr.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a try catch block in your Data access Layer where you are calling the getSomething method and send appropriate response text up the stack. Depending on where you are putting the catch block, you can check if:

```
if(ex.Number == -2)
```

or

```
if(ex.InnerException != null && ex.InnerException.Number == -2)
 return Json(new { successful = false, Message = "Timeout" });
```

and return appropriate response text as a Json response or if only want to handle TimeOutException you can put in the specific catch block for 'Timeout Exception'

```
catch(TimeoutException ex)  
{  return Json(new { successful = false, Message = "Timeout" }); }
```

Comment: forgot to mention that -2 is an identifier for TIMEOUT_EXCEPTION.

Comment: Hmmm I know how I could catch the error in C# and then return it in a JSON object. The problem is that this is MVC ActionResult which returns a PrtialView. return PartialView("_Partial/_View", model); And this model is being handled in the View with a model reference on top  @model App.ViewModels.SomeRepository so not sure how easy it would be to change this to a JSON response?

Comment: Yo can very well return a json response from an action method that returns ActionResult.So in case of this error you will send a Json response and otherwise you will return a partial view. In the success handler of your ajax call you can identify which type of object you have received by checking something like `if(data.Message != undefined)` then show the error else re-render the partial view